# Selenium 'Unable to find matching set of capabilites error'

Tags: python, selenium

When running my Python script which uses Selenium I get this error. Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
File "mypythonscript.py", line 136, in main
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 152, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 188, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Firefox to version >= 52.0.3

Comment: One liners are not the best way to explain solutions to any problem/question. You might wanna explain why you think downgrading FF version would solve the issue here.

Comment: @demouser123 one liners are actually the best way to write a solution. Provided it's descriptive enough (like this answer)